# How to fetch a cleaned gmail message body using Gmail API in python

Tags: python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api, message, payload

I am trying to fetch a cleaned readable gmail message body in python. Below is my code:

```py
message = service.users().messages().get(userId= 'me', id=s_id).execute()
m_dict = { }
m_payld = message['payload']
mssg_parts = m_payld['parts']
part_one  = mssg_parts[0] 
part_body = part_one['body']
part_data = part_body['data']
clean_one = part_data.replace("-","+") # decoding from Base64 to UTF-8
clean_one = clean_one.replace("_","/")           
clean_two = base64.b64decode(bytes(clean_one, 'UTF-8')) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(clean_two , "lxml" )
mssg_body = soup.body()            
m_dict['Message body'] = mssg_body
```

How can I modify the code to give me a better result?

Below is my modified code:

```py
def fetch_mail(mail_id):
    mail_list = []

    for ml_id in mail_id:
        mail_dict = { }
        m_id = ml_id['id'] # get id of individual message
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId= 'me',
                                                 id=m_id).execute() 
        m_payld = message['payload'] # get payload of the message 
        m_head = m_payld['headers'] # getting message payload header


        for sub in m_head: #Fetching the mail Subject
            if sub['name'] == 'Subject':
                m_subj = sub['value']
                mail_dict['Subject'] = m_subj
            else:
                pass


        for dt in m_head: # getting the date
            if dt['name'] == 'Date':
                mail_date = dt['value']
                date_parse = (parser.parse(mail_date))
                m_date = (date_parse.date())
                mail_dict['Date'] = str(m_date)
            else:
                pass


        for sender in m_head: # getting the Sender
            if sender['name'] == 'From':
                m_from = sender['value']
                mail_dict['Sender'] = m_from
            else:
                pass

        try:
            # Fetching message body
            mssg_parts = m_payld['parts'] # fetching the message parts
            part_one  = mssg_parts[0] # fetching first element of the part 
            part_body = part_one['body'] # fetching body of the message
            part_data = part_body['data'] # fetching data from the body
            clean_one = part_data.replace("-","+") # decoding from Base64 to UTF-8
            clean_one = clean_one.replace("_","/") # decoding from Base64 to UTF-8
            clean_two = base64.b64decode(bytes(clean_one, 'UTF-8')) # decoding from Base64 to UTF-8
            soup = BeautifulSoup(clean_two , "lxml")
            mssg_body = soup.body()
            #print(mssg_body)
            mail_dict['Message body'] = mssg_body

        except:
            pass

        mail_list.append(mail_dict)

    return mail_list
```

I ran the script as follows:

```py
mail_details = fetch_mail(mail_id = mail_ids)
```

Now mail_details has only Subject, Date and Sender. There is no error returned and the Message body is not in the result. What should I do?

Comment: What result are you getting with the first code?

Comment: I just redited the question @Jescanellas

Comment: Thanks, but how is the fetched email looking like?

Comment: It returns the mails dates, subjects, sender but no message body.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve the whole message body using Gmail API (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630130/how-to-retrieve-the-whole-message-body-using-gmail-api-python)

Comment: I tried it but its not working.