# How to read in whole message not just snippet

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

```
 msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
 print(msg['snippet'])
```

I am currently using the above code, which doesn't get the whole message. I have seen in the documentation that the google API has raw and full options, but the raw option doesn't print in a readable way and I cannot get the full option to work.

Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve the whole message body using Gmail API (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630130/how-to-retrieve-the-whole-message-body-using-gmail-api-python)

Answer (score 0):

This is how worked for me:

```
# Gets message header first
msg_header = service.users().messages().get(
                                                    userId=user_id,
                                                    id=msg_id,
                                                    format="full",
                                                    metadataHeaders=None
                                                    ).execute()

# Gets message body from header
body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(msg_header.get("payload").get("body")\
            .get("data").encode("ASCII")).decode("utf-8")
```

The body comes in HTML so, in my case, I use BeautifulSoup to extract the information I need, like below:

```
soup = bs(body, 'html.parser')

# Loop on e-mail table
for row in soup.findAll('tr'): 
            aux = row.findAll('td')
            info[aux[0].string] = aux[1].string
```

The information extraction will depend on the pattern of the message. In my case, all messages that I'm getting have the same pattern.